# Keeping Lampshades Tight

Tags: home

Lampshades are usually attached to lamps with a small piece on the top that screws on. These can occasionally loosen by themselves over time, and quite often on second floors of old buildings when the floor regularly shakes (lightly) as people walk by.

When this happens --in a matter of just weeks after tightening the lampshade-- it will begin to rattle. I'll sometimes walk through a room without any carpet and two or three lampshades will rattle as I pass. Is there any way to prevent this *slightly annoying* noise in an otherwise quiet room, and keep these lampshades tightened? I know, it's a funny question.

LOL, it's currently happening every few minutes on my sewing table that keeps shaking from the sewing machine.

Answer (score 3):

A very small amount of blue tack in the screw thread will do the trick

Comment: It would be grateful if you add much information.

Comment: +1 "Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication." *- Leonardo da Vinci*

Comment: Loc-it by Locktite™ will also work to seal the threads preventing loosening of the threaded pieces. When everything else fails, read and follow the simple instructions on the package.

Answer (score 3):

Rubber washers, cut from a bicycle inner-tube, work well. They also help prevent glass shades from cracking.

Answer (score 2):

Applying a small amount of nail polish to the threads should hold tightly and allow you to easily remove the fastener when necessary. You can clean off the nail polish with acetone (most nail polish remover).

If you want to go old school, you can use a dab of linseed oil. I use it as a threadlocker for bicycle repair and it holds tightly but is also easy to loosen when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a product available in construction market known as [mSeal](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=lampshades&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=852&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUo6Tbx57SAhUFpI8KHXHDCzQQ_AUIBigB#safe=active&tbm=isch&q=mseal&imgrc=04HjX3SSyFaNGM:)(in India). I am not branding the product and so suggest you find out an alternative available from your market that works in the same manner.

In this hack, you need to squash mSeal using your bare hands, it will turn into a clay-like substance, apply it to the screws so that it will not get loosen up and make creaky noise further.

Comment: I would appreciate an edit which makes the language use closer to standard English. At the moment it is near impossible to read for me, (and I can read a lot of versions of English without problems.)

Comment: @Willeke As suggested, edit will be made to make it readable for you brother.

Comment: As a female I am not your brother, sister is also not needed. I just asked for everybody who does not speak your version of English. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are having such a problem, how about:  In this situation, you might try crushing some mSeal using your bare hands, it will turn into a clay -like substance.  Apply it to the screw thread and you will find the screw will not loosen up and not make the noises you find so irritating.  Now, was that so difficult???     I myself use a product called Locktite, available in most hardware stores.